# What condition do I need else to show a uniformly continuous is pointwise bounded and uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let a sequence of function f_n uniformly continuous is given. I am wondering what else I need to let it be pointwise bounded and what for uniformly bounded.
I am confused with some knowledge about it. So I believe a generalized argument would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "pointwise continuous"?

Comment: Sorry. I am saying pointwise bounded. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f_n$ is a uniformly continuous sequence of real-valued functions on a metric space $M$ with metric $d$.
If $f_n(x_0)$  is bounded for some $x_0 \in M$, and $M$ is connected, then the sequence is pointwise bounded.

**Proof:**  By uniform continuity, there is $\delta > 0$ such that if 
$d(s, t) < \delta$, then all $|f_n(s) - f_n(t)| < 1$.
Now consider the subset $A$ of $M$ consisting of points $x$ such that there is a
finite sequence $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_m = x$ starting at $x_0$ with $d(x_i,x_{i+1}) < \delta$.  $A$ is nonempty because it contains $x_0$.
If $p \in A$ and $q \in M \backslash A$, then $d(p,q) \ge \delta$.  Thus if
$A \ne M$, $A$ and $M\backslash A$ would form a partition of $M$ into disjoint open sets, contradicting the connectedness of $M$.
Therefore $A = M$.  Now given such a sequence $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_m = x$, 
we have $|f_n(x_i) - f_n(x_{i+1})| < 1$, and therefore 
$|f_n(x)| \le |f_n(x_0)| + m$.  Therefore the sequence is pointwise bounded.

On the other hand, a condition that implies the sequence is uniformly bounded is that $M$ is compact.

Comment: I understand how you get |fn(x)|≤|fn(x0)|+m. But how can you show |f_n(x_0)|  finite. That is if it goes to infinite with n goes to infinite. |fn(x0)|+m is not a finite value. And does M have to be connected?